# Where should I go when I need basic programming issues sorted out?

Tags: discussion

The guidelines of this site state that I should ask for help with problems whose answers not only help me, but help others as well.

This is a big guilt trip for me. I sometimes come up with, what I feel are, stupid questions. I don't really see my questions as worthy of being on a site like this.

For example, I might be met with a reply along these lines: "Ask a real question! Don't bother us with such trifling issues. I am an elitist coder and you should feel dumb for not being able to figure that out on your own!"

That's my experience with coding forums, anyway..

So what is the correct way of asking for help with a tiny tiny problem?

Comment: You're not the worst programmer out there. I don't know whether your questions are stupid, but even if you have stupid questions, other people may have the same stupid questions. Make sure you actually look for an existing answer before posting a question, though; we get pretty tired of seeing the same stupid questions over and over.

Comment: I apologize, Matthew. Will keep in mind for future.

Comment: @CodeMonkey I'm similar to you, but I've never had the courage to ask a question here. When I have seemingly simple (or complex) programming questions (or any topic) I go to IRC (Internet Relay Chat) and sites like webchat.freenode.net and go to the specific channel (topic) or programming language I am needing help with and get the same professional advice and answers in real-time. There's less restrictions and it's pretty casual. Hope it can help you, too.

Comment: Do you use basic learning materials for the programming language you're trying to learn? Books, introductory courses, etc.?

Comment: I'll have to guess that you created this account today because you got question-banned.  If you want useful feedback on what you did wrong, the kind that might actually help you avoid getting banned again, then post a link to your original account so we can see the questions.

Comment: Hehe, your guess is incorrect. This is my normal precautious self, asking ahead of time in FEAR of being banned.

Answer (score 5):

Simply ask your question on Stack Overflow.

The chances are that it's already been asked, so you should search first and pay attention to the questions that are suggested by the system when typing out your question, but if you can't find it post your question.

If it turns out that your question has been asked before but you couldn't find it, someone else will - our users are experts at finding duplicates - and your question will be marked as a duplicate. There's no shame in that as it could be that you didn't know the right terms to search for (that's happened to me).

If your question is new then you'll get an answer which will help you and also help some unknown future programmers. You may be the first encounter the problem, but you won't be the last.